# Facebook Share - codes in description

Tags: wordpress, facebook, share

I've a little problem after changing url and server of my site. At time of sharing url, facebook takes codes (hanacode and jw player code) in description. I want to hide them.

Is there any way to do it?

Visualization of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/417xX.jpg

Comment: Can you paste the link to your site, please? Without it, it's very hard to see what is going wrong.

Comment: You probably haven’t implemented proper Open Graph meta tags, so that Facebook looks at the content of your document and takes a “guess” as to what might be the relevant content … and that can go wrong sometimes.